# Surface Pro - preventing boot loop by changing where boot code is stored

Tags: boot, uefi, microsoft-surface, microsoft-surface-pro

Is there a way to change it so that the Surface Pro boot sequence is loaded from the UEFI MaskROM each time instead of being cached in RAM to prevent a boot loop in the future? I just encountered this issue and fully discharging the battery by repeated robotic power button pressing did in fact fix it but took a long time. https://www.youtube.com/watch?app=desktop&v=efd6X-siFRw in the description says the following quote which is where I got this explanation from.

> The problem is that the bootcode is stored in RAM and this memory can
> under certain circumstances, such as an update, become corrupted.
> Forcing the battery to discharge to 0% clears the RAM and copies the
> boot sequence from the UEFI MaskROM. It's been an issue since SP3 and
> probably accounts for a solid 25% of 'repairs' by this horrible
> company.